# Backbone.Collection.fetch throws "Object [...] has no method '_validate'"

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've got a simple Backbone collection that pulls a list of objects from a (remote) resource. Calling `Collection.fetch`, though, fails with this error:

```
Object [object Object] has no method '_validate'
```

I'm guessing this is happening under the hood when the collection attempts to create a model instance for each JSON object while adding. Can anyone shed some light on why this would happen?

Here's the code I'm using. Very bare bones...

```
/* Models */

var SomeModel = Backbone.View.extend({});


/* Collections */

var SomeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/some/resource/?format=json',
    model: SomeModel,

    parse: function(data) {
        return data.objects
    }
});

var SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    collection: new SomeCollection(),

    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.fetch();
    },
});
```

And here's an example of the resource response:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "count": 100
  },
  "objects": {
    {"title": "Title", "id": 1},
    {"title": "Title 2", "id": 2}
  }
}
```

Comment: Posting code samples when you want help debugging a runtime error is the right way to help us help you.

Comment: See above for code and resource response examples

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably didn't set your collection's `model` option to a valid Backbone.Model subclass. When the collection fetches the data it will instantiate models and call `set`, which will call `_validate`, which a valid `Backbone.Model` subclass will have, but your instances do not. See [the annotated source code for Backbone.Collection.fetch](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html) for details.

Thanks for posting code. here's the problem. Your `SomeModel` extends `View` instead of `Model`. My guess is copy/paste/forget-to-edit.

```
var SomeModel = Backbone.View.extend({});
```

Comment: It would be worth explaining a downvote on this one--@Peter raises a valid point